# Counting number of clusters in data using Self Organizing Map

Tags: neural-network, self-organizing-maps

I roughly know SOM and it is mapping its network to different clusters of trained data.
How to implement to count the number of clusters using SOM? I use KNNL library [here](http://knnl.sourceforge.net/index.html) to implement SOM. In its demo, it is shown how to train and test only. How can I implement it for counting number of clusters? I know I can also use DBSCAN for cluster counting as well. But first, I like to implement SOM for cluster counting. My input data is 2D data representing points in 2D space like

```
(132.181,0.683431),
(136.886,0.988517),
(137.316,0.504297),
(133.653,0.602269),
```

Comment: You might find this answer usefull, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074930/identify-clusters-in-som-self-organizing-map/13089569#13089569